# Extracting network/tree structure from table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, networking, tree, structure

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains several conditions and their individual successors. Some conditions have several successors and these successors might have several successors too. So the goal is extract all possible chains of conditions to achieve something like a tree diagram  in data.
The table looks like this:

```
id  | con | succ
----|-----|-----
1   | a   |  b
2   | a   |  c
3   | a   |  d
4   | b   |  c
5   | b   |  f
6   | c   |  e
7   | c   |  g
8   | c   |  h
9   | d   |  h
10  | d   |  i
```

I still have no clear idea how to store the single chains in the end, but I need the starting point (a), the respective end point and all nodes between starting and end point.
I'm thankful for all kind of advice on how to store the chains and how to extract them.

UPDATE:

This is an extract of my data:

```
ID  | parent_ID
----|----------
403 |   302
404 |   2xx
405 |   303
406 |   304
407 |   304
408 |   2xx
409 |   305
501 |   2xx
502 |   305
503 |   2xx
504 |   2xx
505 |   2xx
506 |   305
507 |   2xx
508 |   306
509 |   2xx
510 |   307
511 |   308
512 |   308
513 |   308
514 |   309
515 |   310
600 |   5xx
```

You see that some parent-IDs are not ID themselves but groups of IDs ('all beginning with 2'). Now the question is how to make the recursive query run or how to make the recursive query handle the '2xx'. The values are stored as characters. Instead of '2xx' another notation is possible aswell.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want your data to come out the query, based on your table data above?

Comment: Not really... For me it's some kind of proof of concept how to storage a network and how to work with / query it. All I can say is that I need all possible path with all nodes listet. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: This is quite different from your original question. What happened to con and succ? Anyway, dealing with '2xx' and the like is not so difficult, but what other notations are possible? Unless there is some system to these "category" notations there is little hope for you.

Comment: Yes, that's different, but @Denis advised me to you use (ID, parent_ID) notation instead of (ID, child_ID) because it's more common. I ran a recursive query on a sample-table, which is structured the same way as my data is. It worked very well. But to use recursive query on my actual data, I need to handle the 'universal' parent_IDs like '2xx'. Instead of '2xx' I could also write only '2' for example, no problem - but the query has to accept it as a group of IDs (all IDs starting with 2). Whether you have a solution or not, could I explain intelligible what the problem is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying tree- and graph-related data stored in a database efficiently is a rather vast topic.

In terms of storage, note that storing an `(id, parent_id)` pair will usually be the better (as in widely accepted) option.

The question is how to query it, and more importantly how to do so efficiently.

Your main options for trees include:

- WITH queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

  Pros: Built-in, and works fine when dealing with small sets
  Cons: Doesn't scale well for larger sets
- MPTT, aka pre-ordered trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

  Pros: Fastest reads for trees
  Cons: Slow writes, hard to maintain unless you do rows one by one
- Nested sets (or intervals) for trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

  Pros: Fast reads for trees
  Cons: Faster than MPTT but still slow, not trivial to understand
- The ltree type in Postgres contrib: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html

  Pros: Built-in, indexable
  Cons: Not ORM friendly

I'd add a hybrid variation of MPTT to the list: if you implement MPTT using `float` indexes, you can get away with not updating anything when moving things around in your tree, which makes things plenty fast. It's a lot trickier to maintain however, because collisions can occur when the difference between two indexes is too small — you need to re-index a large enough subset of the tree when this happens.

For graphs, `WITH` queries work too. Variations of MPTT and nested sets exist as well; for instance the [GRIPP index](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cis4930fa07dm/project/Gripp.pdf). It's an area where research and new indexing methods are still quite active.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, I have a table with the (id, parent_id) aswell, posted the (id, child_id) pairs with no notably reason. MPTT and Nested Sets seem to be quite complicated, so I'd love to work with ltree - seems to be a suitable solution for my purposes. Do you think it's possible to generate the single paths by recursive querying? I'm so sorry that I can't rate your very helpful answers... @Patrick

Comment: In the recursive query's doc, there's an example for a graph that computes the path using `ARRAY[g.id]` and then `path || g.id`. You can use the same field definition for a tree.

Comment: Well, I found another problem: Some IDs have no certain parent_ID but rather a group of parent_IDs. For example: ID 456 is not only the child parent_ID 501 but of all parent_IDs 5xx. Is there a manageable solution to this? @Patrick

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds: Hard to say without seeing the data. Do you mean that IDs are duplicated and having different parent_IDs? Why don't you run the query I posted in my answer and see what you get.

Comment: It would not work. To make it clearer: ID 456 has not another ID as parent_ID. The information stored in parent_ID for ID 456 is '5xx' or in words 'All IDs beginning with 5'

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds: It could still work if you treat your IDs as text labels. Ltree has good pattern matching options that you can exploit. Can you edit your original post with details on the table structure and a sample of real data? (And further comments there such that other readers may find them as well?)

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds: you might have an oriented or non-oriented graph on your hands. If so, Ltree won't work. You'll need WITH queries (see the grah example in the manual) or sophisticated things like GRIPP. To store the graph, use a separate (id, parent_id) table.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to work with the `ltree` data type. See the [documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ltree.html). That does require that you rework your table structure a bit though. If that is not an option, you should look at [recursive with-queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) that can - at first sight - work with your current table structure, but the queries will provide data in a format that is not as easy to manipulate as `ltree` data.

Converting your current table to a ltree variant is best done using a recursive with-query. First you need to create a new table to hold the ltree column:

```
CREATE TABLE tree_list (
  id int,
  chain ltree
);
```

Then run the recursive query and insert the results into the new table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE build_tree(id, chain) AS ( 
  SELECT id, con::ltree || succ
  FROM tree
  WHERE con = 'a'
UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id, build_tree.chain || tree.succ
  FROM tree, build_tree
  WHERE build_tree.chain  ~ ('*.' || tree.con)::lquery)
INSERT INTO tree_list SELECT * FROM build_tree;
```

You will note that the 10 rows of data you provide above will yield 13 chains because there are multiple paths from a to each of e, g and h. This query should work with trees of practically unlimited depth.

```
 id |  chain  
----+---------
  1 | a.b
  2 | a.c
  3 | a.d
  4 | a.b.c
  5 | a.b.f
  6 | a.c.e
  7 | a.c.g
  8 | a.c.h
  9 | a.d.h
 10 | a.d.i
  6 | a.b.c.e
  7 | a.b.c.g
  8 | a.b.c.h
(13 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference on ltree, seems to be a very helpful feature. But it seems that the paths have to be already present to query them with ltree. So would it be possible to generate the paths with recursive querying? Doing that manually would be an incredible high effort... ltree seems to be what I'm looking for, but I have to get the right structure in my data first.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Figured out the recursive query and will try to work with ltree later.